# Can this be done? Is it good pratice (Having an object within the same object)?

Tags: nhibernate

I am using nhibernate and have a table called tiers. A user makes in a form all the tiers they need.

It could look like this

```
Use Teir one up to $600 then use --
Use Teir two up to $1000 then use tier1
Use Tier three up to $1500 then use Tier 1
Use Tier four up to $2000 then use Tier 2
```

In my database I have a field called "useTierAfter". This stores the PK of the tier it should use after the limit.

If Tier two is setup to have $1000 cap anything over that amount would use the tier one amount.

Now what I am not sure is in my fluent/domain nhibernate mapping should I have just a Guid as a property or should I have a Tier object in it?

```
   public class Tier
    {
        public virtual Tier UseTierAfter { get; set; }
        // or
        public virtual Guid UseTierAfter { get; set; }
    }
```

I am not sure what is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, and is perfectly reasonable.  But you're not having an object containing the same object.  Just an object containing a reference to another object of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You should always map the *object* you're relating to, and not foreign keys etc.
So in your example, you would have a `Tier` property, which is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

i think You have a parent child relationship here, which is fine. In the database you can have one table with a foreign key referncing the primary key. In your mapping just map the object. One to many or in fluent with references.